# Contour detection in 2D scatter plot

Tags: contour, triangulation, delaunay, concave-hull, alpha-shape

I am looking for an algorithm, that is able to detect the contour of the attached scatter plot (only for the area y<4, y>4 is not relevant for me). I need that contour to filter out the points that are on it to make some measurements.
Background: The points represent nodes from a meshed part and I want to do some measurements afterwards (see second picture). If someone has any ideas on how I can do this other than using the contour let me know.

I tried different approaches with alpha shapes, concave/convex hull and delaunay but none of them was able to detect the contour correctly.

[image: 2D Scatterplot]
[image: 2D Scatterplot Measured]

Comment: Welcome to SO! A triangulation algorithm that does NOT result in a convex hull (not Delaunay) is "Marching Cubes" See https://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/